# \addcontentsline: lines added to TOC not numbered, and lines added to TOT not shown

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering

Two problems arise when I add lines to the table of contents (TOC), and to the table of tables (TOT):

1. The TOC lines are not properly numbered.
2. The TOT lines don't show on the TOT.

Any idea how to fix that ?

```
%!TEX TS-program = pdflatex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{array}
%------------ 
\newcommand{\SampleTable}{
\begin{table}
\caption{Title of Sample Table}
\begin{tabular}{ l c r }
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
}
%------------ 
\begin{document}
\frontmatter 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}  
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}    
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{section one}
\subsection{subsection one}

\setcounter{subsubsection}{0}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{line added to TOC: subsubsection one}
\addcontentsline{tot}{subsubsection}{line added to TOT: subsubsection one}  

\addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{line added to TOC: subsubsection two}
\addcontentsline{tot}{subsubsection}{line added to TOT: subsubsection two}  

\subsubsection{subsubsection after addcontentsline: three}
\SampleTable
\backmatter
\listoftables

\end{document}
```

Comment: While the `\tableofcontents` uses `toc` for an abbreviation, `\listoftables` uses `lot` (not `tot`). Also, what numbers do you want to add to the ToC/LoT? `\addcontentsline` only adds what you supply, and you didn't supply any number.

Comment: it's "list of tables" (`lot`, accessed by `\listoftables`), not "table of tables".

Comment: I would just like to get to usual latex numbering: 0.1.1.1 for the first line added, 0.1.1.2 for the second line added, 0.1.1.3 for the following subsubsection. ... and thanks for LOT !

Comment: But why are you using `\addcontentsline` manually you should almost never need to do that `\caption` should add the entries automatically to the `lot` and `\(sub)section` should automatically add entries to the `toc`. Also "usual" numbering is 1.1.1 not 0.1.1 you are using `book` so the intention is that all `\section` are within a `\chapter` If you want `\section` to be the top level section unit you should use `article`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here are the two answers, and the resulting code:

1. As Werner mentioned, \addcontentsline doesn't include the numbering of the line added, according to the level where it was added (ex.: subsubsection). So, we have to add the numbers (value of the chapter, value of the section, value of the subsection, value of the subsubsection), with the help of counters (see http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Counters).

   ```
       \addtocounter{subsubsection}{1}
       \addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}~~ line added to TOC: subsubsection one}
   ```

A better option is pointed out by Werner (comment below): \protect\numberline{\thesubsubsection}

```
        \addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{\protect\numberline{\thesubsubsection} line added to TOC: subsubsection one}
```

2. Indeed, TOT doesn't exist, but "lot" does.

   ```
   %!TEX TS-program = pdflatex
   \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
   \usepackage{array}
   %------------ 
   \newcommand{\SampleTable}{
   \begin{table}
   \caption{Title of Sample Table}
   \begin{tabular}{ l c r }
     1 & 2 & 3 \\
   \end{tabular}
   \end{table}
   }
   %------------ 
   \begin{document}
   \frontmatter 
   \setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}  
   \setcounter{tocdepth}{5}    
   \tableofcontents
   \newpage

   \part{part one}
   \chapter{chapter one}
   \section{section one}
   \subsection{subsection one}

   \addtocounter{subsubsection}{1}
       \addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}~~ line added to TOC: subsubsection one}

   \addtocounter{table}{1}
   \addcontentsline{lot}{section}{\arabic{table}~~~~ line added to TOT: subsubsection one}  

   \addtocounter{subsubsection}{1}
   \addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}~~ line added to TOC: subsubsection two}
   \addtocounter{table}{1}
   \addcontentsline{lot}{section}{\arabic{table}~~~~ line added to TOT: subsubsection two}  

   \subsubsection{subsubsection after addcontentsline: three}
   \SampleTable
   \backmatter
   \listoftables

   \end{document}

   %% Reference on counters: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Counters
   ```

And the code with Werner's better option:

```
    %!TEX TS-program = pdflatex
    \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
    \usepackage{array}
    %------------ 
    \newcommand{\SampleTable}{
    \begin{table}
    \caption{Title of Sample Table}
    \begin{tabular}{ l c r }
      1 & 2 & 3 \\
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    }
    %------------ 
    \begin{document}
    \frontmatter 
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}  
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{5}    
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage

    \part{part one}
    \chapter{chapter one}
    \section{section one}
    \subsection{subsection one}

        \addtocounter{subsubsection}{1}
        \addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{\protect\numberline{\thesubsubsection} line added to TOC: subsubsection one}

    \addtocounter{table}{1}
    \addcontentsline{lot}{section}{\arabic{table}~~~~ line added to TOT: subsubsection one}  

    \addtocounter{subsubsection}{1}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{\protect\numberline{\thesubsubsection} line added to TOC: subsubsection two}
    \addtocounter{table}{1}
    \addcontentsline{lot}{section}{\arabic{table}~~~~ line added to TOT: subsubsection two}  

    \subsubsection{subsubsection after addcontentsline: three}
    \SampleTable
    \backmatter
    \listoftables

    \end{document}

    %% Reference on counters: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Counters
```

Comment: I truly don't understand what is going on here... but instead of using `\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}`, you can just use `\protect\numberline{\thesubsection}`. Compare that to adding `\subsubsection{test}` somewhere, and look at the indentation/spacing. `\numberline` is the macro that sets the sectional unit number in a box of specific width, making things line up properly.

Comment: It may seem weird to try to number TOC lines with \addcontentsline, whereas that command is intended to produce unnumbered TOC lines. In fact, in my book, sometimes in the text, I don't want the "title" of the subsubsection to be shown because it takes space, and I need that space for the image I put afterwards. But, I want the image to be indicated in the TOC at the subsubsection level, well numbered. ... Thanks for the other better option for numbering !

Comment: @Werner: Your comment made me work a bit with the \numberline definition, but being a newby I must confess that many things are still unclear. In particular, why do you need \protect in this setting?