# Adding Subsubsection & Subsubsection* to the TOC with lyx?

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, numbering, lyx

I'm using, lyx 2.0.2, how can I add the Subsubsection in a document with a report class to the TOC, I tried the solution provided in this [Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101538/addcontentsline-lines-added-to-toc-not-numbered-and-lines-added-to-tot-not-sh) but didn't work for me, it generated no errors but no Subsubsection is added to the TOC.
Now I have a couple of section* I added those with this:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Conclusion}
```

But when I tried to do the same with Subsubsection or Subsubsection* it didn't work:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{subsubsection label}
```

**Note:** that the Subsubsection are not numbered in a report class, and that's how I want them to be added to the TOC.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to Document --> Settings --> Numbering & TOC. Move the lower slider so that subsubsections is listed as appearing in TOC.

This is equivalent to

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
```

As explained in the answer to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17877/how-to-show-subsections-and-subsubsections-in-toc?rq=1) question.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me