# Sections in ToC with links but without headings

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, hyperref, koma-script, links

I want to include some external documents (PDFs) in the appendix of the document I am writing.  I would like to have these included documents listed in my table of contents, but no section heading should be typeset where they appear in the main document.

The setup I constructed with the help of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101566/15173) (included below) works fine, except that the links made by `hyperref` in the ToC all point to the start of the appendix.  How can I get links in the ToC that point to the `section`s?

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{hyperref,scrpage2}

\newcommand*\silentsection[1]{
  \addtocounter{section}{1}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection}#1}
  \sectionmark{#1} % this is to get headers for the section
}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\automark{section}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{main}
\clearpage\section{part}
\clearpage\section{with}
\chapter{some}
\clearpage\section{sections}

\appendix
\chapter{included documents}

\silentsection{one}
Yada.

\cleardoublepage
\silentsection{two}
Yada yada.

\cleardoublepage
\silentsection{three}
Yada yada yada.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\phantomsection` just before your `\silentsection` command.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: That works, thanks!  If you want to post that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manual additions to a Toc (or LoF/LoT etc) via `\addcontentsline` often require a `\phantomsection` statement for correct linking, as well as for the bookmarks.

A more elaborate way would apply the `\phantomsection` command in `\silentsection`...

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{hyperref,scrpage2}

\newcommand*\silentsection[1]{%
  \addtocounter{section}{1}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection}#1}
  \sectionmark{#1} % this is to get headers for the section
}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\automark{section}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{main}
\clearpage\section{part}
\clearpage\section{with}
\chapter{some}
\clearpage\section{sections}

\appendix
\chapter{included documents}
\phantomsection
\silentsection{one}
Yada.

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\silentsection{two}
Yada yada.

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\silentsection{three}
Yada yada yada.

\end{document}
```