# Side-by-side figures are reversed in LOF (Bidi - XeTeX)

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, xetex, minipage, bidi

I'm typesetting an Arabic document using XeLaTeX. I'm using it for about a year now.

The problem I couldn't solve or find a solution for yet is when putting two figures side-by-side, the figures are in the correct order (RTL) in the document but they are reversed in the list of figures.

My minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1]{KacstOne}

\newcommand{\dblimg}
  [7][ht]{{\begin{figure}[#1]
             \begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}\centering
               \includegraphics[width=#2\textwidth]{#3}
               \caption[#4]{\centering #4}
             \end{minipage}\hfill
             \begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}\centering
               \includegraphics[width=#5\textwidth]{#6}
               \caption[#7]{\centering #7}
             \end{minipage}
           \end{figure}
         }}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\dblimg{1}{a.jpg}{111}
       {1}{a.jpg}{222}

\end{document}
```

The output:
[image]

The `\dblimg` takes the width, path, and caption of the two images.

As you can see, Figure 1 (on the right) is listed before Figure 2; the figures are in the correct order in the document, but not in the list of figures.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  What an interesting question.

Comment: Thanks, Jan! I usually ask only when I can't find the solution anywhere. :D

Comment: eddin: Al hail the internet :-)  Sorry, that I am not speaking arabic.

Comment: Jan: No problem! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First with `caption` package  you can remove figures from lof with `\caption[]{your caption}`, then you can replace them with manual entry

```
\addcontentsline{lof}{subsection}{\arabic{tempfig}\qquad your caption}
```

Where `tempfig` is a counter which store the value of figure counter  before side by side images

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1]{Amiri}

\newcounter{tempfig}

\newcommand{\dblimg}
  [7][ht]{%
  \setcounter{tempfig}{\value{figure}}
  \stepcounter{tempfig}
  \addcontentsline{lof}{subsection}{\arabic{tempfig}\qquad #4}
  \stepcounter{tempfig}
  \addcontentsline{lof}{subsection}{\arabic{tempfig}\qquad #7}
  \begin{figure}[#1]
             \begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}\centering
               \includegraphics[width=#2\textwidth]{#3}
               \caption[]{\centering #4}
             \end{minipage}\hfill
             \begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}\centering
               \includegraphics[width=#5\textwidth]{#6}
               \caption[]{\centering #7}
             \end{minipage}
           \end{figure}
         }

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\dblimg{1}{example-image}{111}
       {1}{example-image}{222}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I found 2 issues:
1. If Fig number is prefixed (e.g., with the chapter number), it will be w/o the prefix in LOF.
2. The space between Fig number and caption in LOF is fixed, but all captions should be aligned.
After [searching](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101566) and trying, the solution for 1 is using `\thefigure` directly, and for 2 is to add `{\protect\numberline{\thefigure}#4}`. So before `\begin{figure}` we need `\stepcounter{figure}\addcontentsline{lof}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thefigure}#4}` twice (for each image), and after `\end{figure}` we need `\addtocounter{figure}{-2}`

Comment: In this case you get شكل ٣ and شكل ٤, I think you mean: add `\addtocounter{figure}{-2}` before  captions of  figures

Comment: Good catch! My code (in the previous comment) fixes the numbers in LOF but increases the figures numbers in the document by 2. This is [the revised code](https://gist.github.com/noureddin/094bf5531e2c02d9e64517e53ccc0673); it should work fine now.